# Pandas - get max row value if there's a zero and get mean value if there are no zeros

Tags: pandas

In this df:

```
      points_made  points_conceded 
0     0.00         30.00           
1     10.00        30.00
```

How do I create a 'points_expected' column, where the column value is the `max()` row value if there is any `0.00`, and the `mean()` on `axis=0`, if there are no `0.00`, like so:

```
      points_made  points_conceded points_expected
0     0.00         30.00           30.00
1     10.00        30.00           20.00
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `replace` with `NaN`

```
df['new'] = df.replace(0,np.nan).mean(1)
df
   points_made  points_conceded   new
0          0.0             30.0  30.0
1         10.0             30.0  20.0
```

Comment: in my real case scenario, there are other columns I do not want to get the mean of. is there a way to declare the columns the mean should be applied to?

Comment: @8-BitBorges  df[[youcol1,yourcol2....]].replace(0,np.nan).mean(1)

Comment: @8-BitBorges you can use implement your desired logic in `func(row)` and use the method explained in my answer

Comment: thank you. i've upvoted your solution but accepted this one for its simplicity

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'points_made': [0, 30],
    'points_conceded': [10, 30]
})

def func(row):
    if 0 in list(row):
        return max(row)
    else:
        return row.mean()

df['new'] = df.apply(lambda row: func(row), axis=1)
df
```

returns:

```
    points_made     points_conceded     new
0   0               10                  10.0
1   30              30                  30.0
```